# "\N" is converted into 0 in mysql using mysqlimport, I want to avoid that and I need a null instead

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I want to avoid that and I need a null instead of `0`.

sample date delimited by "}"

```
InActive}null}ANO149089}2017-07-17 12:50:46.903}\N}EME}
```

below I need after `mysqlimport` to be:

```
InActive null ANO149089 2017-07-17 12:50:47 . EME
```

PS: I want to achieve it through `mysqlimport` without having to change anything in the text file

Comment: `\N` will be converted to `NULL`, not `0`.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to transform data using `mysqlimport`. You'd need to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` so that you can assign the input column to a variable, then use a `SET` clause to convert it to a different value in the table.

Comment: I found a solution.  adding --fields-escaped-by='\\' in mysqlimport options handles the \N to be null and not zero.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar  I will do it. can you me help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394430/mysqlimport-default-character-set-delimiter-terminated-by-%CE%BC-for-loading

Comment: Sorry I never use `mysqlimport`, I don't know how to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

mysqlimport -u rwuser -p$passwd -h "host"  --local  abc_schema  xyz.txt --fields-terminated-by='μ' --lines-terminated-by='\n' --fields-escaped-by='\\'

\N in a text file won't get converted into ( 0 default) using the above for an int type.